# MySQL server Connection Error

Tags: mysql

I have virtual server hosted and this is my configuration of VPS..

ubuntu 14.04 with tomcat 8 and java 8 and i installed mysql 5.5.40

I created a new user in it with

```
CREATE USER 'ram'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '*****';
```

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'ram'@'localhost'`;

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

upto this all okay and executed perfectly..

I want to connect to this database from mylocal machine using mysql Workbench

I give ip and username it says

`unknown mysql server host 'ip' (2)`

I know this question is already asked so many times and i tried all of that answers,but none worked for me,so only i raised this question again here..

Already i asked in stackoverflow and came here

Comment: 'ip' must be 'localhost' not some remote IP

Comment: i give locahost only in server..

Comment: Try by giving the grant all privileges to your local machine ip and access the MySQL from your local machine.

Comment: I tried that also ,it's not working..

Comment: i can connect to my other servers from my mysql workbench,but not this server alone

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple reasons. Some are listed below.

**USER IS NOT CREATED TO CONNECT FROM ANY HOST**

You need to create user with command listed as below

```
CREATE USER 'ram'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '*****';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'ram'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Basically it will allow **ram** user to connect from any host, as you are trying to connect to VPS MySQL from your local machine. If you create the **ram** user with **localhost**, you will able to connect from **VPS** itself.

**PORT IS NOT OPEN**

Also you need to check that, the port is open on which you want to connect. That is default **3306**.

You can use **TELNET** utility to check that whether your VPS is listening on port **3306** from your local machine or not.